# Cocoon Forms definition file

Tags: xml, forms, xsd, apache-cocoon

Having defined a business model in **XML**, is it possible to programmatically define from that same model a [**Cocoon Forms**](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/forms/1.0/) **form definition file** (a sample form definition file is available in the [docs](http://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/forms/1.0/478_1_1.html)) from an XSD Schema?

Is there any method to produce such definition files from within Cocoon Forms itself, or by using some other tool (something like an **XSLT** transformation)?